# Protocol associated type that conforms to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

**Code**

I have the following protocols:

```
protocol BaseViewController {
    typealias ViewModelType: BaseViewModel

    var viewModel: ViewModelType? { get set }
}

protocol BaseViewModel {
}
```

I also have the following protocol for a view model:

```
protocol MainViewModel: BaseViewModel {
}
```

Then in my MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, BaseViewController {
    typealias ViewModelType = MainViewModel

    var viewModel: ViewModelType?

    ...
}
```

**Errors**

On the MainViewController I get the error

`Type 'MainViewController' does not conform to protocol 'BaseViewController'`

Below this are two related errors:

1. On BaseViewController:

`Unable to infer associated type 'ViewModelType' for protocol 'BaseViewController'`

2. In MainViewController on the viewModel property

`Inferred type 'BaseViewModel' (by matching requirement 'viewModel') is invalid: does not conform to 'BaseViewModel'`

**Desired Result**

I would like to restrict the value of ViewModelType to conform to protocol BaseViewModel.  If this can be accomplished another way, then that will answer my question.  But I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a concrete implementation of protocol `BaseViewModel` so defining `MainViewModel` as a struct or class would work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for typealias indicates it has the following format:

> typealias-assignment → =­ type­

And `type` is defined as:

> type → array-type­  dictionary-type­  function-type­  type-identifier­
>   tuple-type­  optional-type­  implicitly-unwrapped-optional-type­ 
>   protocol-composition-type­  metatype-type­

And `protocol-composition-type` is defined as:

> protocol-composition-type → protocol­<­protocol-identifier-list­opt­>­

So listing a protocol does not seem to be supported, so it's not clear why you're not getting a compilation error there. If you change it to that format, it seems to work (compiles but I have not tested you get the desired result):

```
protocol BaseViewController {
    typealias ViewModelType = protocol<BaseViewModel>

    var viewModel: ViewModelType? { get set }
}
```

And:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, BaseViewController {
    typealias ViewModelType = protocol<MainViewModel>
```